# How can I include a related link data in Sugar module while using fields param in GET request of SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have REST api in SugarCRM 11.
I need to fetch all records from one module that should contain the related records data from the link.
But I dont want to fetch the link in separate api calls.

I have used as below:

```
https://mysugarapp.com/rest/v11_5/MYMOD_MODULENAME/filter?fields=name,date_confirmed,opportunities
```

Here, `opportunities` is a link that I need to include some of its fields in my response JSON.

Oficial docs says to include as a json in the fields GET params.

```
/filter?fields=name,date_confirmed,{"name":"opportunities","fields":["col_1","col_2"]}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late. But I leave the answer here...

These parameters will work properly:

```
?fields=name,date_confirmed,opportunities,{"name":"opportunities","fields":["col_1","col_2"]}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made some workarounds for my project but will definitely use this in future modules.